# Are there statistics of which music genres are the most succesful economically nowadays?

Tags: genre

I was reading this article [The Broader Music Industry](http://www.ifpi.org/content/library/the-broader-music-industry.pdf) and it stated

> The recorded music industry is the engine helping to drive a much
>   broader music industry, worth more than US$130 billion globally

This is probably an old report though, but the point is that it made me think, is it known how much money the music industry makes nowadays separated by music genres? I suppose this is difficult to calculate since some songs fuse genres or are between 2 genres or more, but is there any estimate or something?

Comment: I think [this article on The DataFace](http://thedataface.com/2016/09/culture/genre-lifecycles) or [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4453253/) can serve as a starting point for US stats? Though, I'm contemplating "the most popular genre" with "the most successful economically genre"...